# Convert Dictionary of List of Dictionaries to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary in the structure given below and I need to convert it into a Pandas Dataframe to do some aggregation operations. But I couldn't able to convert it into given output format

```
{
  "raj": [
    {
      "subject": "science",
      "score": "35",
      "create_time": "1595990288421"
    },
    {
      "subject": "maths",
      "score": "40",
      "create_time": "1595980800000"
    }
  ],
  "dev": [
    {
      "subject": "science",
      "score": "23",
      "create_time": "1595990288421"
    }
  ],
  "mag":[
    {
      "subject": "science",
      "score": "41",
      "create_time": "1595990288421"
    },
    {
      "subject": "maths",
      "score": "25",
      "create_time": "1595980800000"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need the output dataframe to be in the given format

```
name    subject     score   create_time
------------------------------------------
raj     science     35      1595990288421
raj     maths       40      1595980800000
dev     science     23      1595990288421
mag     science     35      1595990288421
mag     maths       25      1595980800000
```

Can anyone help me convert the dictionary into required dataframe output ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': k, ** j} for k, v in data.items() for j in v])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  name  subject score    create_time
0  raj  science    35  1595990288421
1  raj    maths    40  1595980800000
2  dev  science    23  1595990288421
3  mag  science    41  1595990288421
4  mag    maths    25  1595980800000
```